# Java page load library

Tags: java, pingdom, http-monitor

I need to write some web page load measuring Java tool with the same functionality as at http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ or http://pageload.monitis.com/pagespeed.jsp. I need to measure page and all its embedded elements load time. Tool should have no GUI. 
Is there some Java library for such purpose? If not, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private instance of WebPageTest would do what you want - it can be driven via it's API

There's a description of how to setup and 'all in once' instance here - http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/09/18/how-to-create-an-all-in-one-webpagetest-private-instance/

Ping me if you want more details on how to do more complex things with it